# Arduino loop one time

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

I want to run this for loop which on `abc()` function only one time. But it works continuously. What should I do?

```
const int buttonPin = 2;
int buttonState = 0;
int i;

void setup() {  
    pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void abc(){
    if (buttonState == HIGH) {
        for(i=0; i<240; i++)
        {
            analogWrite(6,i);
        }

     }
     else {
         analogWrite(6,0);
     }
 }

void loop() {
    buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
    abc();
}
```

Comment: Is this for real? Have you actually read anything about the (very simple) `setup`/`loop` scheme used in Arduino projects??? How about calling `abc` from `setup` (or better yet, just take the code of function `abc` and put it in function `setup`).

Comment: Is this possible to call function from setup. I don't know actually

Comment: Why wouldn't it be??? And in any case, you could simply put that code directly in there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some boolean in IF statement, like this:

```
bool ABC = true;

void loop() {
    if(ABC) {
        abc();
        ABC = false;
    }
}
```

I hope it's help.

Yoav

Comment: That's a very bad advice I'm afraid. This variable needs to be `static`, otherwise it will be initialized to `true` every time the `loop` function is invoked. And even if you answered it correctly, the Arduino scheme is designated specifically to allow the programmer to perform certain things only once - simply perform them in the `setup` function. There's no reason to use a Boolean flag here whatsoever.

Comment: You are right. I meant that he need to declare a global variable. I see that i don't write it right. Thank you for your comment. i change the answer.

Comment: Sorry i do some mistakes in English, i delete my comment.

Comment: I kept it as global . but i also tried it in void loop(). It does not show me output which i am expecting

Comment: OK, but: 1. If the global variable is not used anywhere else outside the function, then it is a better coding convention to declare it as a static local variable inside the function (so that no one else in the future will ever decide to make any use of it). 2. As I've already mentioned, with the Arduino's project scheme, this is totally redundant. You should simply do your "one-time" operations in the `setup` function (and not in the `loop` function, as you suggest in your answer).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i'm completely agree, but he asked to do that in the loop. I did not think he does not know the difference between the setup() and the loop().